Python select EPOLLEXCLUSIVE Invalid argument with Python 3.11.2 and Linux Kernel 6.1.0-26-amd64
I'm experimenting with Python's select.epoll module to see which events I can register and listen for.
I tried to register events using this code:
import socket
import select


def main():

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as server_socket:
        server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))
        server_socket.listen(10)

        with select.epoll() as epoll:
            SELECT_EVENT_TYPES = (
                select.EPOLLIN |
                select.EPOLLOUT |
                select.EPOLLPRI |
                select.EPOLLERR |
                select.EPOLLHUP |
                select.EPOLLET |
                select.EPOLLONESHOT |
                select.EPOLLEXCLUSIVE | # error
                select.EPOLLRDHUP |
                select.EPOLLRDNORM |
                select.EPOLLRDBAND |
                select.EPOLLWRNORM |
                select.EPOLLWRBAND |
                select.EPOLLMSG
            )
            epoll.register(server_socket.fileno(), SELECT_EVENT_TYPES)

This produces a runtime error:
    epoll.register(server_socket.fileno(), SELECT_EVENT_TYPES)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

If I remove select.EPOLLEXCLUSIVE, then this function succeeds.
It seems odd that this doesn't work when all the other values of the enumeration work.
The documentation says

Added in version 3.6: EPOLLEXCLUSIVE was added. It’s only supported by Linux Kernel 4.5 or later.

but this should be ok, because I am running a much later version of Python than this and a much newer kernel too.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html

Should what I am trying to do work?
